# Limitation of versionRetentionPeriod in Cloud Spanner PiTR

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, data-recovery

What is the limitation and cost of using versionRetentionPeriod in Cloud Spanner Point-in-time recovery (PITR)?

Answer (score 0):

versionRetentionPeriod can be increased to up to 7 days. Here are the documentation links that explain the performance and cost implications of increasing versionRetentionPeriod https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/pitr#performance https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-pitr#estimate-storage